# Text and Image Highlighted same time

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do a menu.

http://jsfiddle.net/yagogonzalez/pVcQG/

I want the image and the text hightlighted at the same time. When the mouse is over the image, the text is highlighted, but when the mouse is over the text, the image doesn't change.

By the way, I'm not able to remove the image border with `border-style: none;`.

I hope anyone can help me. Thanks a lot!

```
<div class="iniciocenter">
    <div class="bloqueinicio">
        <a href="?page_id=7">
            <img class="imghover2" style="background-image: url('http://www.aprendicesvisuales.com/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/images/inicio/nosotrosh.png');">nosotros
        </a>
    </div> 
    <div class="bloqueinicio">
        <a href="?page_id=8">
            <img class="imghover2" style="background-image: url('http://www.aprendicesvisuales.com/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/images/inicio/cuentosh.png');">cuentos
        </a>
    </div> 
</div>
```

**Style**

```
.iniciocenter {
    text-align: center;
}
.imghover2 {
    width:190px;
    height:190px;
}
.imghover2:hover {
    background-position:0px -190px;
}
.handlee{
    font-family: handlee;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-size: 1.714rem;
    line-height: 1.285714286;
    margin-bottom: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
.bloqueinicio {
    display:inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: handlee;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-size: 1.971rem;
    color: #365F8B;
    width:190px;
    height:50px;
}
.bloqueinicio a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #375F8F;
}
.bloqueinicio a:hover {
    color: #FF8000;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the below to the CSS to get the image highlighted on hovering the text.

```
.bloqueinicio a:hover .imghover2{
    background-position:0px -190px;
}
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/pVcQG/3/)

**EDIT:** The border appears when the `img` tag is used without a `src` attribute (as kind of a placeholder for the image). Here you are placing the image as a background. Hence, my suggestion would be to use an empty `div` tag instead of the `img` tag like shown below to do away with that border.

```
<div class="bloqueinicio">
    <a href="?page_id=7">
        <div class="imghover2" style="background-image: url('http://www.aprendicesvisuales.com/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/images/inicio/nosotrosh.png');">
        </div>
        nosotros
    </a>
</div>
```

[**Demo Fiddle 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/pVcQG/7/)

**Additional Info:** You might want to have a look at [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827965/is-putting-a-div-inside-an-anchor-ever-correct) also prior to implementing the suggestion mentioned in the edit. Basically it says as per HTML 4.01, block level elements weren't allowed inside `<a>`. But with HTML5, it is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1):

Change your HOVER rules like this:

```
.bloqueinicio:hover .imghover2 {
background-position:0px -190px;
}

...

.bloqueinicio:hover a {
color: #FF8000;
}
```

See the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/H7DFA/

Answer (score 1):

edit `.imghover2:hover` class like this :

```
.bloqueinicio a:hover img {
    background-position:0px -190px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/pVcQG/5/